# Clearcase application impact with April 2014 MS patch

Tags: clearcase, windows-server-2003, ibm-rational

Do you know of any impact on the ClearCase application for the [below mentioned Microsoft patches](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a1a33778-88b7-452a-9133-c955812f8910/entry/content_released_in_patches_for_windows_english_april_2014_security_bulletins?lang=en)?

My environment is Win 2003 Enterprise SP2

- Security Bulletin Risk    Description KB Number
- MS14-017 Critical Vulnerabilities in Microsoft Word and Office Web Apps Could Allow Remote Code Execution KB2949660
- MS14-018 Critical Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer KB2950467
- MS14-019 Important Vulnerability in Windows File Handling Component Could Allow Remote Code Execution KB2922229
- MS14-020 Important Vulnerability in Microsoft Publisher Could Allow Remote Code Execution KB2950145

Comment: Normally, we apply windows patch regularly, and if we don't get warning from IBM/Rational, we apply the windows patch directly.

In case, if you are not sure, please raise ticket to IBM/Rational for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the ClearCase running on your server:

- simple Base ClearCase client
- ClearCase Vob server
- CCRC server

Unless you see a warning from IBM, you can proceed with the installation, and double-check with IBM (communicating at least the full version of your ClearCase setup: `cleartool -verall`)

You can see some general advises [in this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013748445):

> - VOB servers are specialized. Normally patches and service packs provide no benefits or improvements.
> - Does your IT department test patches and service packs before installing them enterprise wide? Blindly trusting any windows upgrade/sp has been empirically shown to be a Bad Idea(tm).
> - Get management involved. Yes patches and sp's are important, but so is having a working VOB server. If folks understand the risks to the company, they'll be more keen to work out a compromise. (Don't fall for the "we'll give you control of the server and you'll be in charge of patching it.")

Comment: ,Any particular place in IBM site I go and check this ?

Comment: @maestromani no official place that I know of. Best is to contact IBM support for confirmation.